# Adding a .deb file to my local mirror (Ubuntu)

Tags: ubuntu, packages, mirroring

I have a local Ubuntu repo mirror and a debian package. Since the package is restricted to use in my local setup, I just want to add it to my mirror rather than as a PPA on launchpad. Therefore, I want to do some changes in my local repo so that the user can do a simple apt-get install package-name and get the package installed on their machines.

Answer (score 0):

The question is really old, but good to have an answer:

- The easiest way is to make local or flat Debian repository. Then add it to the list of mirror sources.

  Reference: [wiki.debian.org/DebianRepository/Format#Flat_Repository_Format](https://wiki.debian.org/DebianRepository/Format#Flat_Repository_Format)
- Option 2, inject deb package into the mirror and set mirror configuration to not delete obsolete packages or set an exception.

  Anyway, OP didn't mention his mirroring tool. For example  `reprepro` supports adding external packages, ref: [wiki.debian.org/Multistrap/PartialMirrors#Adding_packages](https://wiki.debian.org/Multistrap/PartialMirrors#Adding_packages)